# Restoring Nuget Package Cache?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I deleted all of the packages in my global-packages cache, and now my projects are throwing lots of CS0012 for standard library constructs:

```sh
error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
error CS0012: The type 'IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I've run:

- `dotnet restore` in the solution and each project throwing the errors.
- `nuget restore` in the solution and each project throwing errors.

My dotnet configuration:

```sh
> dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   3.0.100
 Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.19025
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 3.0.0
  Commit:  7d57652f33

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

Why did deleting the global-packages cache cause this problem and how do I recover from it?

Edit:

Here is the final .csproj which is throwing these errors:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="GraphQL" Version="2.4.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="GraphQL-Parser" Version="4.1.1" />
        <PackageReference Include="dotNetRDF" Version="2.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.2" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Your project still reference netstandard? If yes, there's a warning sign?

Comment: @Emanuele I updated the question to include the .csproj file for reference, if that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I mean: check inside your visual studio project if there are any warning near the package (like here https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjfwsSivfblAhXkwAIHHZg7AbsQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F5909042%2Fvisual-studio-2010-adding-sl-project-reference-in-non-sl-project-results-in-warn&psig=AOvVaw0DLDbmvDfg0SZglEuM252y&ust=1574259899106041)

Comment: I don't see any, here is what VS sees: https://imgur.com/a/neuk6qX

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542) with versions of visual studio before 15.5 (or rather the associated msbuild).
The summary is that you either need to upgrade to the latest version of VS2017  or use VS2019.
Alternatively, if you don't want to do that, it looks like inserting the following reference in all failing csproj files (or just your Directory.Build.Props to be safer) should do the trick:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="netstandard" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Another suggested workaround is to use the target frameworks property rather than the singular version. E.g.:

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
```